# How do I change the SVM kernel in LibSVM?

Tags: java, weka, libsvm

I have this code:

```
LibSVM classifier = new LibSVM();   
classifier.setKernelType(null);
```

I would like to set it to a linear kernel. However, it seems that I am unable to change the parameter as it requires a SelectedTag value. How do I instantiate a class of this?

I have read the documentation on [KERNELTYPE_LINEAR](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable/weka/classifiers/functions/LibSVM.html#KERNELTYPE_LINEAR).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by doing this:

```
LibSVM classifier = new LibSVM();  
classifier.setKernelType(new SelectedTag(LibSVM.KERNELTYPE_LINEAR, LibSVM.TAGS_KERNELTYPE));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import libsvm.svm_parameter; // import this header   
LibSVM svm = new LibSVM();
    svm_parameter pre= new svm_parameter();
    pre.kernel_type= svm_parameter.POLY;
    pre.gamma= 3;
    pre.degree=1;`
    svm.setParameters(pre);
    svm.buildClassifier(data);
```

Comment: I can't comment on the relative correctness of this answer as opposed to the earlier, simpler, and the-way-I've-done-it answer, but I can't let your one code comment stand: '// import this header'.  This isn't C, and the "import" statement doesn't "import" any "header"; it directs the compiler to search the indicated namespace for the desired classes. Just sayin'. ;-)